# Why is this wrong? C++ Analysing Date and Time

Tags: c++

I've been writing a function as a way of analysing the date and time of a string but I can't see where I've gone wrong.

No matter what date or time is entered e.g 99/99/9999 99:99 gives a value of 0 to z. It's seems to be a really simple code and an incredibly long winded way so I assume I've made a simple mistake. Could you have a look for me, it would be incredibly helpfully.#

My only thought was that because it was a string not a integer that this wasn't registering and therefore causing the error but the code I used to fix it

istringstream(mystring)>>T&D;

Did nothing.

```
if (pos != string::npos)
        {
        mystring=mystring.erase (0,13);
                       {      
                         int z=0;

                         if (isalpha(mystring[0])) z+1;
                         cout << z << endl;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[1])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[3])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[4])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[6])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[7])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[8])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[9])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[11])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[12])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[14])) z+1;
                         if (isalpha(mystring[15])) z+1;

                         if (mystring[0] > 3)  z+1;
                         cout << z << endl;  
                         if (mystring[3] > 1)  z+1;  
                         if (mystring[6] != 2)  z+1;    
                         if (mystring[7] != 0) z+1;      
                         if (mystring[8] != 1)  z+1;       
                         if (mystring[9] != 4)  z+1;
                         if (mystring[11] > 2)  z+1;
                         if (mystring[14] > 6)  z+1;


                       cout << mystring << "\n" << z << endl;

                            if (z != 0 ) {cout << "Please enter a valid Date & Time" << endl;}


                       }
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `z+1` to do? Increment `z` by 1???

Comment: Also, `mystring=mystring.erase (0,13);` is kindof deleting your string

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? It's a valid Stack Overflow question even though the code is extremely poor.

Comment: @CashCow 100% agree. It's a perfectly fine question for SO

Comment: @MatthiasB Not deleting it, but the assignment is certainly unnecessary, and could cause problems if he later converts to the more idiomatic forms of `std::string::erase` which use (and return) iterators.

Comment: And of course, I'll never tire of saying it, but `isalpha( mystring[i] )` is undefined behavior.

Comment: The mystring.erase removes the unwanted text

Comment: originally: Date & Time: 11/12/1213 12:13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
if(pos != string::npos) 
{
    mystring = mystring.erase(0, 13); 
    int z = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < mystring.Length(); i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(mystring[i])) z++;
    }
    if((int)mystring[0]-'0' > 3) z++;   //(int)mystring[0]-'0' converts it to int.
    if((int)mystring[3]-'0' > 1) z++;
    if(mystring[6] != '2') z++;        //No conversion needed for !=
    if(mystring[7] != '0') z++;
    if(mystring[8] != '1') z++;
    if(mystring[9] != '4') z++;
    if((int)mystring[11]-'0' > 2) z++;
    if((int)mystring[14]-'0' > 6) z++;

    if(z != 0) 
    {
     cout << "Please enter a valid Date & Time" << endl;
    }
}
```

(for-loop is better than one million ifs and changed to `z++` instead of `z+1`)

Answer (score 0):

`z+1` is just a value, one more than z. It doesn't increase `z`;

You probably want `++z;`

In your statements. `if(mystring[0] > 3` (as an example) you are actually comparing a char to a number, the equivalent 8-bit integer. If you actually mean the character `'3'` that is not the same value.

By the way, you might find it easier to do all the above with a regex.